# How to share a User Hashmap between different socket processing in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, ownership

Hi I am new into Rust and I am learning Async(tokio crate) and Ownership. In order to do that I am developing a chat server for which I want to have some basic Log In options. For that I use a HashMap saving the user as key and password as value. The code goes like this:

```
   async fn main(){
      let mut users_map: HashMap<String,String> = HashMap::new();
      let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8881").await.unwrap();
      //stuff
      loop{
          let (mut socket, addr) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
          //more stuff
          tokio::spawn( async move {
               if users_map.contains_key(&user)==true{ //Here is the problem
                     //more stuff
                     users_map.insert(user, password);
               }            
          }
      }
}
```

So according to what I read in the Rust book, when I use that if, the value moves to that statement so I cant lose it out of that scope. But then how can I do operations with the Hashmap defined for all the scope? I tried cloning, but if I clone it, I would create a Hashmap for each connection acceptance, so that is really bad, because I want a shared Hashmap for all the 'tasks'.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, you have to play with the Arc, Mutex, See this [doc](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state)

Comment: You could also use a `RwLock` instead of a `Mutex` if you expect only infrequent writes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Arc` and `scc::HashMap` especially in an asynchronous code block (I'm self-advertising it - note that I'm the author. https://crates.io/crates/scc). Basically, you need an `Arc` and a concurrent hashmap.

```rust
async fn main(){
    let mut users_map: Arc<scc::HashMap<String, String>> = Arc::new(scc::HashMap::default());
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8881").await.unwrap();
    //stuff
    loop{
        let (mut socket, addr) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        let users_map_clone = users_map.clone();
        //more stuff
        tokio::spawn( async move {
            if /* '!' should be what you wanted here */ !users_map_clone.contains_async(&user).await {
                users_map_clone.insert_async(user, password).await;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Or, as others pointed out, you could also use `Arc<tokio::Mutex<std::collections::HashMap<_, _>>>`. I don't particularly recommend `std::sync::Mutex` here since blocking code does not quite harmonize with asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arc`, and `DashMap`. `DashMap` is from `dashmap` crate. e.g.:

```
let users_map = Arc::new(DashMap::<String, String>::new());
...
loop {
    let map_clone = users_map.clone();
    tokio::spawn( async move {
        if map_clone.contains_key(&user)==true{ //Here is the problem
            //more stuff
            map_clone.insert(user, password);
        }            
    }
...
```

Comment: Note: using `dashmap` in async code might cause deadlocks if you accidentally hold locks/references to the map across `.await` points. See [this issue](https://github.com/xacrimon/dashmap/issues/233). I ran into this when one Tokio task was calling `retain`, while another was doing `let e = map.entry(); db_query().await; e.do_something();`. It can happen that Tokio schedules this as `entry, db_query, retain`. The `retain` cannot do its work as locks into the map exist, so it blocks, causing a deadlock. Dashmap can work with async code, but you have to be careful.